# android ViewPager with one recycler view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i have a TabLayout on top of recyclerview

[image]

now i want to implement viewpager with tablayout and when user swipe the recyclerview it change the data in that recyclerview

** note that i dont want to use difrrent pages , just that recyclerview with diffrent data

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad. You can follow [this](https://github.com/stanmishra/NewsStarApp) link to implement viewpager with recyclerview.

In this project the tab adapter(inside MainActivity) is set like this:

```
val adapter = TabAdapter(supportFragmentManager) 
adapter.addFragment(YourFragment.newInstance(“TabName1”)) 
adapter.addFragment(YourFragment.newInstance("TabName2”))
adapter.addFragment(YourFragment.newInstance("TabName3”))
viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

Based on the parameter(tabname1,tabname2 etc.) you can set different data in different fragment instance.